# ngFor is not working for array of images in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am working with Angular4. Here, I am getting an object on changing the state and in that object an array of images are present. I am trying to display the images in a carousel using `ngFor`. But it is showing an error and nothing was displayed. Below is my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product-details',
    templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    public productInfo:any;
  
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            const data=params;
            this.productInfo=data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productInfo));
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:300px;height:400px;background-color:lightgrey">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" *ngFor="let image of productInfo.images">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="{{image.src}}" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

By declaring `productInfo` as an array also I am not getting the data. I have tried `ngFor` for the object also but it doesn't work. Where I did the mistake?
My Sample object data:
{"id":"18","name":"Apple laptop","slug":"apple-laptop","permalink":"https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/product/apple-laptop/","date_created":"2017-03-28T09:20:55","date_created_gmt":"2017-03-28T09:20:55","date_modified":"2017-09-22T09:05:55","date_modified_gmt":"2017-09-22T09:05:55","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":"false","catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"

The moment you open your MacBook, its gorgeous 12-inch Retina display with edge-to-edge glass brings everything into focus. Every photo leaps off the screen in rich, vibrant detail.

\n","short_description":"

Over three million pixels render each letter with crystal clarity. And it all comes to light on the thinnest Retina display ever on a Mac, meticulously honed to deliver a bold visual experience within an impossibly minimal design.

\n","sku":"","price":"200000","regular_price":"200000","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":"null","date_on_sale_from_gmt":"null","date_on_sale_to":"null","date_on_sale_to_gmt":"null","price_html":"$200,000.00","on_sale":"false","purchasable":"true","total_sales":"60","virtual":"false","downloadable":"false","downloads":"","download_limit":"-1","download_expiry":"-1","external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":"false","stock_quantity":"null","in_stock":"true","backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":"false","backordered":"false","sold_individually":"false","weight":"","dimensions":"[object Object]","shipping_required":"true","shipping_taxable":"true","shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":"0","reviews_allowed":"true","average_rating":"4.00","rating_count":"1","related_ids":"467,35,8,468,9","upsell_ids":"","cross_sell_ids":"","parent_id":"0","purchase_note":"","categories":"[object Object]","tags":"","images":"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]","attributes":"[object Object]","default_attributes":"","variations":"","grouped_products":"","menu_order":"0","meta_data":"","_links":"[object Object]"}

Comment: how does your object look like?

Comment: what do you get in console on, console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productInfo))

Comment: Iam getting the object data

Comment: @srujana can you post sample object data ?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: [src]="image.src"

Answer (score 0):

As you are directly binding the data to ProductInfo it is not showing response data in UI. We can in fact create a model class having the same members as that of your json response. Bind the locally created class object to *ngFor to get the data shown in UI.

Example:
Your json response is,

```
"Product" : { "id": 1, "name" : "srujana"}
```

create,

```
export class ProductItems{
    id : number;
    name : string;
}
```

Now create an object of this class in your component class and bind the response to it

```
export class YourClass{
    ProductItemObj : ProductItems[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ProductItemObj  = data;
        this.productInfo= ProductItemObj ;
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I have many properties present in object data.Then is it right to create an object in a class with that many properties?

Comment: You need not have all the properties in the class. Only the ones which you would like to show in UI can e added to the class.

Comment: Type 'Params' is not assignable to type 'ProductItems[]'.Iam getting this error.

Comment: You need to assign data to your object array. If declaring const is not necessary then u can define data as any.

Answer (score 0):

2 Things,

It's good to prevent bad loading.

So put an *ngIf of your List before the *ngFor.

```
*ngIf="productInfo && productInfo.images"
```

and try

*[src]="image.src"*
in

```
<img [src]="image.src" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image data must be base64 data url encoded or url and use property binding

```
<img [src]="image.src" />
```